# How to run one JQuery event before the other one when both events are fired at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I am trying to run two JQuery events at the same time. When there is only one of them active they both do work but if they are active together, only one event is fired.

One event is listening for when the input loses the focus, the other one is for getting the text of a live search result. My thought was to hide the result div once the input loses the focus (user clicks on something different). The other event is for getting the result as already mentioned when the user clicks on something in the result div and hide it afterwards.

```js
$(document).on("focusin", 'input.mdb-min-input', function(event) {
  $("div.result").html('<p class="live-results"> Test1 </p><p class="live-results"> Test2 </p>');
});

$(document).on("click", '.live-results', function(event) {
  console.log("click!");
  $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
});

$(document).on("blur", 'input.mdb-min-input', function(event) {
  console.log("blur!!");
  $(this).siblings(".result").empty();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Jquery Events</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="search-box">
    <input class="mdb-min-input" type="text" />
    <div class="result z-depth-1">
      <p class="live-results"> Test1 </p>
      <p class="live-results"> Test2 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"> </div>
  <div class="search-box">


</body>

</html>
```

. The problem is that only the blur event is fired.

I have already tried to change the order of both events but this doesn't help. 
I will provide you the code.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that the blur event would happen before the click event is processed, in which case it may be the case that the element are being removed before the click can register as being on them.  I would probably move the results removal into the click handler to see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Sure, it fixes the problem, but the removal has to be in the blur handler, otherwise I wouldn't need it. Isn't there a way to change the order?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  The mouse is focused in the input.  I'm assuming it has to revert that state of the browser before it can apply the focus state of other things.